# Converting java cipher crypto code to node js crypto

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, node-crypto

I have a encryption/decryption functionality in java code and wanted to write the same logic using the **crypto** node-js library.
What's the equivalent of these Java codes ?

Java code :

```
 String iv = "Some random string";
 AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
```

What I tried :

```
const iv = "Some random string"
var ivSpec = new Buffer.from(iv);
```

Java code :

```
String key = "Some random key";
SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
```

What I tried :

```
const key = "Some random key"
var newKey = new Buffer.from(key);
```

Java code :

```
String message = "Some message"
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(textBytes.getBytes());
```

In java code it is using **"AES/CFB/NoPadding"** and I found equivalent in node js crypto i.e **"aes-256-cfb"** so I used it.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cfb', newKey, ivSpec);
cipher.update(message, 'utf8');
cipher.final();
```

Is that correct ? Where I am doin it wrong cause there is no output of cipher.final().
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *...Is that correct?...* Have you compared the results of the two codes? Depending on the mode, `final()` takes padding into account or generates/checks an authentication tag. Although both are irrelevant for CFB (and `final()` returns nothing), it's more robust to concatenate the results of the `update()` and `final()` calls (e.g. with respect to a change of the mode).

Comment: Could you add some resources to go deeper into this? Thanks

Comment: See the *crypto* documentation. For more details see the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/src/crypto/crypto_cipher.cc#L889). Note that *crypto* is just an OpenSSL wrapper, `final()` essentially calls the OpenSSL functions `EVP_CipherFinal_ex()` and `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl()`. See their OpenSSL documentation for more details.